# How to convert string to time datatype in pyspark or scala?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, azure-databricks, pyspark

Please note that I am not asking for `unix_timestamp` or `timestamp` or `datetime` data type I am asking for `time` data type, is it possible in pyspark or scala?

Lets get in details,
I have a dataframe like this with column `Time` string type

```
+--------+
|    Time|
+--------+
|10:41:35|
|12:41:35|
|01:41:35|
|13:00:35|
+--------+
```

I want to convert it in `time` data type because in my SQL database this column is `time` data type, so I am trying to insert my data with spark connector applying `Bulk Copy`
So for bulk copy my both data-frame and DB table schema must be same, that's why I need to convert my `Time`column into `time` data type.

Appreciate Any suggestion or help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The following was run in the PySpark shell, the datetime module does allow time format

```
>>> t = datetime.datetime.strptime('10:41:35', '%H:%M:%S').time()
>>> type(t)
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

When the above function is to be applied on the dataframe using the map, it fails as the PySpark doesn't have a datatype time and it's unable to infer it.

```
>>> df2.select("val11").rdd.map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x[0]), '%H:%M:%S').time()).toDF()

TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'datetime.time'>
```

The `pyspark.sql.types` module for now only supports the below datatypes

```
NullType
StringType
BinaryType
BooleanType
DateType
TimestampType
DecimalType
DoubleType
FloatType
ByteType
IntegerType
LongType
ShortType
ArrayType
MapType
StructField
StructType
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
df.withColumn('time', F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp(F.col('time'), 'HH:mm:ss'), 'HH:mm:ss'))
```